# php combine 2 functions in class

Tags: php

Im trying transfer this funcs in class

```
function trim_value(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);    // this removes whitespace and related characters from the beginning and end of the string
}
array_filter($_POST, 'trim_value');
```

Here my try:

```
public static function trimValue(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}
public static function trimArray($array)
{
    array_filter($array, Request::trimValue);
}
```

but not working, was trying with call_user_func, call_user_func_array, but not working too, help with solution please!

Comment: What does _not working_ mean.  Also, `trimArray(&$array)` probably need a reference.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, how can i do that, example please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.  In your current usage, you need to pass `$array` by reference with a `&`.  Also, your callback should be either a string `'Request::trimValue'` or `array('Request', 'trimValue')`.  `self` also works instead of `Request`. Finally, `array_filter()` isn't what you want.  Try `array_walk()`:

```
public static function trimValue(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}
public static function trimArray(&$array)
{
    array_walk($array, 'self::trimValue');
}
```

Comment: your way return clean array! array = (); after ur way i got clean array!

Comment: no =), before: array = (1 = > 'text1', 2 = 'text2'), after trimArray i got array = ()

Comment: not working too, instead of cleaning , i use concatenation

Comment: AbraCadaver any solution please! why `&` not working?

Comment: Edited.  needed `array_walk()` sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use return instead of reference. Edited trimArray.

```
public static function trimValue($value)
{
    return trim($value);
}

public static function trimArray($array)
{
    return array_map(["Request", "trimValue"], $array);
}

public static function trimAndFilterArray($array)
{
    return array_filter(self::trimArray($array);
}
```

Use as such:

```
$trimmedValue = Request::trimValue($originalValue);
$trimmedArray = Request::trimArray($originalArray);
```

Test:

```
class Request 
{
public static function trimValue($value)
{
    return trim($value);
}

public static function trimArray($array)
{
    return array_filter(array_map(["Request", "trimValue"], $array));
}
}

$originalValue = " test ";
$originalArray = [" test ", " ", "test ", " test"];

$trimmedValue = Request::trimValue($originalValue);
$trimmedArray = Request::trimArray($originalArray);
var_dump($trimmedValue, $trimmedArray);
```

Result:

```
string(4) "test"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

*Edit* separated the trim and filter into its own method.

Comment: not working, instead of cleaning , i use concatenation (return $value.'something') and i got the same array

Comment: your answer working with array_map not with array_filter

Comment: Ah yes, used array_filter instead of array_map.

Comment: and without array_filter just array_map

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static function trimArray($array)
{
    return array_filter($array, array('Request', 'trimValue'));
}
```

It's not working because [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) expects a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as the second parameter. In PHP, you can specify a callable in a couple of different ways, with the above being one way to pass a `callable`.

I also agree with @OIS that you should change both of your functions to `return` a value, rather than pass by reference, but that's more stylistic.

Comment: @AbraCadaver nice catch, didn't realize it was static. updated

Comment: your answer is not for my question